# Permission set not availble in Change set!

Tags: community, deployment, permission-sets, change-set, experience-cloud

While deploying a community, got the below error

**In field: permissionSet - no PermissionSet named <permission_Set_name> found**

I created an outbound change set, after "ADD"
under Component Type = Permission Set, I am unable to find the required permission set in the list.

Comment: Can you check this article. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YaFAAU&title=permission-set-cannot-be-found-in-list-of-components-in-either-inbound-outbound-change-set

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi I compared Permission Set, Email Template, and Email Template Folder name.. but there's no match between them!
According to article everything seems fine in my org

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I had the same issue, but later on figured out that because the Permission Set that I've been using is a clone of a different set, its API name was the original PS API name but with "_clone" as a suffix, and that API is what I needed to look for in the list of permission sets in my change set.
Hope that it helps